# Most performant of Two SQL Double joins

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables that use the same compound key and I want to join them with a left join. Is my 1st query below the right way to do this, or would joining against B a second time as in my 2nd example be better/more performant? I should also mention that these tables exist on opposite sides of a database link, so I am thinking that less joins would be better...

Table A:

```
key1 | key2 | field
--------------------
1    | 1    | frog
1    | 2    | fish
3    | 2    | erik
```

Table B:

```
key1 | key2 | otherField
---------------------------
1    | 1    | "three times"
1    | 3    | "rarely"
2    | 2    | "once"
```

Desired Result:

```
key1 | key2 | field | otherField
---------------------------------
1    | 1    | frog  | "three times"
1    | 2    | fish  | null
3    | 2    | erik  | null
```

**Method 1:**

```
select * 
from A
left join B on (A.key1 = B.key1)
where (B.key2 = A.key2 or (B.key1 is null and B.key2 is null));
```

**Method 2:**

```
select *
from A
left join B b1 on (A.key1 = b1.key1)
left join B b2 on (A.key2 = b2.key2)
```

Comment: What do your tests show you?

Comment: @Tom H Method 1 seems slower than I'd thought but it's probably not related to this question. I haven't tried 2 yet. I am not sure if they are equivalent

Comment: Try a simple left join on both keys.

Comment: The filtering logic is similar, but the results won't be the same. In method 2 you will get all of the columns from table B returned twice, because you joined it twice.

Comment: @Parfait thanks, I didn't realize you could do that. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Someone else did but they deleted it already.

Comment: I agree with @Parfait , this should be a pretty straight forward left join `select A.key1, A.key2, A.field, B.otherField from A left join B on A.key1=B.key1 and A.key2=B.key2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply left join on both keys:

```
SELECT A.key1, A.key2, A.field, B.otherfield
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
  ON (A.key1 = B.key1) 
 AND (A.key2 = B.key2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this also appears to be much faster than my "Method 1"